# How to print a vector to stdout in ghostscript

Tags: postscript

I would like to get the StandardEncoding vector out of postscript (there is a graphical version in Appendix E.6 of PLRM, but no text).  I am looking for something along the lines of [/A /B /C /D], but in truth anything I can regex to relate position in encoding vector to character command would be good.

I have tried

```
(%stdout)
(w)
file
/StandardEncoding
writestring
```

but it (obviously) doesn't work as /StandardEncoding is not a string.  How would I print a vector like this to the stdout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest.

```
StandardEncoding ==
```

Or with indices. Decimal:

```
0 StandardEncoding { exch dup =only(: )print 1 add exch == } forall pop
```

Octal:

```
0 StandardEncoding { exch dup 8 3 string cvrs =only(: )print 1 add exch == } forall pop
```

Hex:

```
0 StandardEncoding { exch dup 16 2 string cvrs =only(: )print 1 add exch == } forall pop
```

Also, you should know that `/StandardEncoding` is a *literal* name (because of the `/`) so the name itself sits on the stack. If you had gone the next step and converted to a string, it would have simply printed the word "StandardEncoding". So, to automatically load (and possibly execute) the value associated with a name, drop the slash (`/`) so the name is *executable*. The word `StandardEncoding` (without the slash!) becomes the vector. The slash works much like `quote` in Lisp-family languages.

For illustration, here are some more ways both to print things and to iterate over arrays.

```
StandardEncoding {
    (%stdout)(w)file exch 80 string cvs writestring
    (%stdout)(w)file (\n) writestring
} forall

StandardEncoding
0 1 2 index length 1 sub {  % Arr i
    2 copy get 80 string cvs print  % Arr i
    (\n) print  % Arr i
    pop  % Arr
} for

[ StandardEncoding 0 {
    {
        2 copy get ==only
        ()=
        1 add
    } loop
} stopped cleartomark
```

This last one uses an infinite loop and traps the `rangecheck` error that is signalled when `get` tries to read a non-existent element. It would leave 5 values on the stack (`StandardEncoding 256 StandardEncoding 256 true`) which you could discard with `cleartomark` as shown, or simply `pop pop pop pop pop` (or `5{pop}repeat`).

*Edit:* Further playing with the last example. This isolates the error trapping to the operator that is expected to throw the error. Isolating the expected errors lets any unexpected ones print the usual diagnostic.

```
[ StandardEncoding 0 {
    2 copy
    { get } stopped { exit } if
    ==only ()=
    1 add
} loop cleartomark
```

Comment: Thank you, the first one is simple and does the job perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You could use "==" and "forall":

```
([) =
StandardEncoding { == } forall
(]) =
```